# Get all arrays in between two elements in a multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, foreach

Please I need help. I have a PHP difficulty. This is multidimensional array and I want to get all the arrays in between "Credit Agreements Summary" arrays and "Credit Agreements" arrays into a separate array entirely. I have tried to use range() function but its not getting it. Thanks in advance.

This is a data example:

```
[
 [
        {
            "x": 28,
            "y": 119,
            "str": "Credit Agreements Summary",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 160,
            "height": 12,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 545,
            "y": 156,
            "str": "Account",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 30,
            "height": 8,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 549,
            "y": 166,
            "str": "Status",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 22,
            "height": 8,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 490,
            "y": 156,
            "str": "Facility",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 27,
            "height": 8,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 479,
            "y": 166,
            "str": "Classification",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 49,
            "height": 8,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 434,
            "y": 156,
            "str": "Arrear",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 24,
            "height": 8,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 432,
            "y": 166,
            "str": "Amount",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 29,
            "height": 8,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 365,
            "y": 156,
            "str": "Instalment",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 40,
            "height": 8.25,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        },
        {
            "x": 28,
            "y": 126,
            "str": "Credit Agreements",
            "dir": "ltr",
            "width": 104,
            "height": 12,
            "fontName": "g_d101_f412"
        }
 ]
]
```

Comment: Does this fully represent realistic data? It looks like you only need to remove two subarrays.  Is this aways true?  More importantly, WHY do you think you need to perform this data mutation?  Don't you know which `str` values that you will be targetting?

Comment: Are there ever any elements before the `Credit Agreements Summary` subarray? Are there ever any elements after the `Credit Agreements` subarray? You logical requirements are not clarified by your sample data.

Comment: I'm so sorry for not replying yet, This response you are seeing is a pdf extraction data by coordinates. I only want to get data in between Credit Agreements Summary and Credit Agreements. So yes, there are data before and after the two elements, massive in fact. So I'm not targeting the str yet in this step, I only want to get all the arrays in between the two elements an array separately. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Credit Agreements Summary" and "Credit Agreements" are always going to be the first and last items, you can do it like this:

```
$result = array_slice($data[0], 1, -1);
```

If that's not necessarily true, it's a little more complex. Here's one way to do it:

```
$result = [];
$copy = false;
foreach ($data[0] as $row) {
    if ($row->str == 'CreditAgreements') {
        break;
    }
    if ($copy) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
    if ($row->str == 'CreditAgreementsSummary') {
        $copy = true;
    }
}
```

Basically just iterate the data, start copying items into a new array after you reach the starting marker, and stop the iteration when you reach the ending marker.

Comment: thanks to you, your second method put me well on track, I had to bring this first:

`if (trim(strtolower($c['str'])) == 'credit agreements summary') {
  $copy = true;
}`

this second:
`if (trim(strtolower($c['str'])) == 'credit agreements') {
  $copy = false;
  break;
}` 
then lastly
`if ($copy) {
  $result[] = $c;
}`